# how to remove characters from python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the follow python code which is a list. For some reason I get unwanted characters in the list how can we remove these characters from the beginning and end of list.

```
stuff = []
a = ('{"type": "push"}')
stuff.append(a)

print(stuff)
```

outputs

```
['{"type": "push"}']
```

How can we remove the `['']` and output like

```
{"type": "push"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing the following :

```
 a = ('{"type": "push"}')
```

you are appending a string (`type(a)` returns `str`). What you might want instead is to append a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
a = {"type": "push"}    # ===> output = [{"type": "push"}]
```

which will give you the right output

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assuming that a will be a tuple. However, that's not the case. In your current implementation it will be a string. That's why when you append(a) the whole string gets appended. Use any other data structures and there is no need of extra quotes that you don't require to be present.